# Java: Run multiple while loops at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, while-loop, thread-sleep

I'm trying to make several `JRadioButtons` blink at the same time with this blink method:

```
private void blink(JRadioButton button, boolean blinking)
{
    if(blinking)
    {
        while(true)
        {   
            try 
            {
                button.setSelected(true);
                Thread.sleep(500);
                button.setSelected(false);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        button.setSelected(false);
    }
}
```

I know it has something to do with threads but I'm not that familiar with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to make several JRadioButtons blink at the same time with this blink method

IMHO you don't need multiple while loops.

Just add all buttons you want to blink to an `ArrayList`, then in the same `while` loop, loop over that list and blink the buttons. So, instead of

```
button.setSelected(true);
Thread.sleep(500);
button.setSelected(false);
Thread.sleep(500);
```

You can use

```
for(int i=0; i<yourList.size(); i++) {
    yourList.get(i).setSelected(true);
}
Thread.sleep(500);
for(int i=0; i<yourList.size(); i++) {
    yourList.get(i).setSelected(false);
}
Thread.sleep(500);
```

But this is a bad practice. Use the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class and schedule a thread to execute every `500`ms instead:

```
Timer t = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
    boolean selected = false; 

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        selected = !selected;
        for(int i=0; i<yourList.size(); i++) {
            yourList.get(i).setSelected(selected);
        }
    }
});
t.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't animate the GUI by using `Thread.sleep`. In fact, you must never call `Thread.sleep` on the Event Dispatch Thread because that very thread is in charge of repainting the GUI, which it will clearly not be able to do while sleeping.

What you must use is the Swing Timer class and schedule it to repeat at the desired interval.

Comment: It's possible that the posted code runs on a different thread (not the EDT). But that of course is still wrong as you must not call Swing methods from another thread.

Comment: @davmac Precisely. And if the code were to be corrected with `invokeLater`, then it would be turning into an ugly mess and use an extra thread for no good purpose.